# How to get docker-compose do not remove containers during down after up --rm or build --no-cache used

Tags: docker, docker-compose, spring-batch

I used some command to ask docker-compose to not use the cache when i was developing, now i need it to reuse the containers as one of them is a (very lightweight) database for spring batch.

it seems like it caches this setting somewhere.

sample output:

```
[user@hostname myFolderName]$ docker-compose down # or stop, actually
Stopping myFolderName_batch_1    ... done
Stopping myFolderName_batch-db_1 ... done
Removing myFolderName_batch_1     ... done # stop doing this!!!
Removing myFolderName_batch_run_1 ... done # what is run???
Removing myFolderName_batch-db_1  ... done # stop doing this!!!
Removing network myFolderName_default
```

Comment: so i think its actually `docker-compose up --no-recreate` but i dont have the time to check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this command returns the docker-compose cache to the state of reusing containers:

`docker-compose up --no-recreate`

Answer (score 2):

use `docker-compose stop` in order to stop de containers without removing them